# Can someone check for me where I did wrong?

Tags: mysql

```
select s1.emp_no as emp_no,(s1.salary - e1.salary) as growth from (
select salaries.emp_no,salary from salaries
where from_date in (select to_date from salaries)
and to_date = '9999-01-01') as s1
inner join (
select e.emp_no,s.salary from employees as e
left join salaries as s
where e.hire_date = s.from_date) as e1
on s1.emp_no = e1.emp_no
order by growth
```

Hi guys, I'm new to sql and doing exercise from a website right now(similar to leetcode)
about one question, above is my code and it works fine when I test it.
However, on the website it says my code is wrong:

```
SQL_ERROR_INFO: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where e.hire_date = s.from_date) as e1\non s1.emp_no = e1.emp_no\norder by growth' at line 8"
```

I have no idea where I did wrong, can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

P.S if someone wants to test it self, below is the table:

```
drop table if exists  `employees` ; 
drop table if exists  `salaries` ;
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
`emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`birth_date` date NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
`gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
`hire_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`));
CREATE TABLE `salaries` (
`emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
`from_date` date NOT NULL,
`to_date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`,`from_date`));
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(10001,'1953-09-02','Georgi','Facello','M','2001-06-22');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(10002,'1964-06-02','Bezalel','Simmel','F','1999-08-03');
INSERT INTO salaries VALUES(10001,85097,'2001-06-22','2002-06-22');
INSERT INTO salaries VALUES(10001,88958,'2002-06-22','9999-01-01');
INSERT INTO salaries VALUES(10002,72527,'1999-08-03','2000-08-02');
INSERT INTO salaries VALUES(10002,72527,'2000-08-02','2001-08-02');
```

Comment: It's `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... WHERE` so watch the order.

Comment: @tadman yea, i need to change 'where' to 'on', thx for your help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` requires a join condition, i.e. with an `ON` or `USING` clause. The `WHERE` clause may satisfy the same logic, but not the required syntax.

Wrong:

```
select e.emp_no,s.salary from employees as e
left join salaries as s
where e.hire_date = s.from_date
```

Right:

```
select e.emp_no,s.salary from employees as e
left join salaries as s
  on e.hire_date = s.from_date
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html for full reference documentation on `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks! No idea why it works fine when I test on https://sqlbolt.com/ :(

Comment: They must have a different SQL parser implementation than MySQL.